# Work Laptop keeps reseting desktop background from stretch to tile

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Anyone else run into this issue? It is not the problem of HP/Compaq listed here: [Changing desktop background picture from stretch on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/77770/13751)

What I am finding is that my Windows 7 Laptop (it is a Thinkpad, but with non HP installed OS) allows me to set a wallpaper background, I can set it as stretched or tiled, etc; however upon reboot, the wallpaper always defaults to 'tiled'. It never saves it to Stretched which is the best approach for my monitors.

Anyone run into this? Or could it be some corporate 'reset' for wallpaper? I do recall for Windows XP we run BGINFO, but I don't get the background being updated on my machine to reflect the background details.

Running Windows 7 64bit Professional

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it reverts back to tiled and its a work laptop makes me think this may be a Group Policy setting by your work's system administrators.  Perhaps it was set and forgotten...  Check with them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right mouse desktop, goto Personalize, then Display (bottom left corner of the window).

It will bring up a "Make it easier to read" window. By default, my installation was set at 150% and I ended up with the same problem with BGInfo and AWC (Automatic Wallpaper changer). Setting it to 125% or less seemed to fix it.

Comment: I've always had it at 100%, so no change for me here, and setting to 125% then 100% DOES reset the wallpaper, but again, it doesn't save for next time, I can just re-apply the wallpaper 'stretch to fit' mode and it works the same for the session.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I suspect Keltari's right about it being a group policy.

My solution: make a stretched copy of the image that is exactly the monitor's resolution.  This only works if you have a single monitor or all of your monitors are the same resolution, but in my case I have dual 1440x900 so I'm fine.

Answer (score -2):

I used MSCONFIG to kill BGINFO from starting and that fixed the issue. I have admin rights on my machine though.